# Do data and residuals of a VAR model have to be of normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, autoregressive

Does vector autoregression ([VAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_autoregression)) model require data to be of normal distribution? What are the pitfalls if the residuals are not of normal distribution?

Comment: The question is too general(vague). Please, try to focus on the aspects you are interested on.

Comment: VAR models are regressions. Hence the usual regression assumptions apply. On the other hand, since VAR model admits MA($\infty$) representation, if errors are normal then the data should be normal too. The coefficients are usually estimated using OLS, hence their estimates are robust to non-normal disturbances. However if you have cointegration, the usual tests are sensitive to normality, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you. From what I understood for linear regression Yi = b0 + b1*Xi + ei,

1) b1 ~ N( ) requires Yi ~ N( ).

```
a) Thus, I don't need Xi to be normal. 

b) And Yi not being normal => b1 not normal
```

If I only want to get the coefficients but are not using the p-values, I don't need Yi to be normal.

2) a) E(ei) = 0 and "ei have constant variance and are uncorrelated"

```
=> b) E(b1) = beta1; and 

   c) "b1 has minimum variance among all unbiased linear estimators of beta1"
```

If I don't need (2b) and (2c), I don't need (2a).

Am I right?

P.S. Does anyone know how to get the p-values of the coefficients if I am using mAr.est() in R?

Comment: Please either update your question, or post a new one mentioning this one. Answers are for answering. Judging by your text, 2 separate questions can be asked.

Comment: *1) b1 ~ N( ) requires Yi ~ N( )* seems wrong to me (at least asymptotically). *And Yi not being normal => b1 not normal* seems wrong to me (at least asymptotically).